# how to send the mails to updated users when trigger fires?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I created a trigger in mysql table, when trigger fires, how can I sent the mail.
Can I call a php file from mysql trigger or else if any other way I have, if any one knows could you help me out

Comment: You can let the trigger fill up a table with emails which need to be send. Then create a scheduled job to call a php script which reads the table and sends the emails.

Comment: i have tried a lot with lib_mysqludf_sys library,but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

According to [MySQL bug #41094](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41094) you cannot do system call from triggers.

Though, [this](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.fr/2011/12/call-external-program-from-mysql.html) could be a solution for your case.